# How I can get all my credits and badges I lost when my former employer killed my corporate email account?

Tags: support

How I can get all my credits and badges I lost when my former employer killed my corporate email account?

Comment: Are you still able to log in with your old account? If so you could try to go to your Profile > Settings > My Loings > Add new Login

Comment: No, I am not able to log in with my old account for the company I worked. I am able to log in only with my personal account. If my old account for the previous company I worked will be still available to me, I would not be here asking this question.

Comment: Any clue over there?